# using struct typedef in multiple .c & .h files

Tags: c, compiler-errors, typedef

A directory holds the following files:

1. "car" files:

a. car.h:

```
#ifndef __CAR_H__
#define __CAR_H__

typedef struct car car_t;
...
(some functions declarations)
...
#endif /* __CAR_H__ */
```

b. car.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "car.h"

typedef struct car_node
{
   void *data;
   struct car_node *next;
   struct car_node *prev;
} car_node_t;

struct car
{
   car_node_t head;
   car_node_t tail;
};
...
(some functions implementations)
...
```

c. car_main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "car.h"

int main()
{
   ...
   (some tests)
   ...
}
```

2.  "vehicles" files:

a. vehicles.h

```
#ifndef __VEHICLES_H__
#define __VEHICLES_H__

typedef struct vehicles vehicles_t;

...
(some functions declarations)
...

#endif /* ifndef __VEHICLES_H__ */
```

b. vehicles.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "car.h"
#include "vehicles.h"

struct vehicles
{
   car_t carlist;
   void *data; 
};
```

c. vehicles_main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "car.h"
#include "vehicles.h"

int main()
{
   ...
   (some tests)
   ...
}
```

When compiling the following with a makefile, everything works great:
car.c, car_main.c.

But when I compile the following files with a makefile: car.c, vehicles.c, vehicles_main.c, I get the following error:

```
vehicles.c: error: field ‘carlist’ has incomplete type
```

My question is: Why the compiler doesn't recognize the typedef car_t, found inside car.h, if car.h is included inside vehicles.c?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that inside `vehicles.c`, the compiler needs to know what a `car_t` actually *is*, and you've only provided it what it should be *called*. What a `car_t` actually *is* is defined in `car.c`. To fix this, you'll either have to make `carlist` a pointer (since the compiler doesn't need a complete type for that), or you'll have to move the structure definition to the `.h` file:

`car.h`:

```
typedef struct car_node
{
    void *data;
    struct car_node *next;
    struct car_node *prev;
} car_node_t;

typedef struct car {
    car_node_t head;
    car_node_t tail;
} car_t;
```